# Trying to understand which Log methods are omitted when releasing a debug and official release app?

Tags: android, debugging, logcat, android-log

Inside Log explanation in android site i couldn't understand the following sentence:

> You should never compile verbose logs into your app, except during development. Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime, while error, warning, and info logs are always kept.
> Blockquote

Does it mean that in release version all logs that was written by Log.e, Log.i,Log.w are saved inside the phone and Log.d, Log.i are omitted?

I read it in:
[Android Site](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)